# Mounting windows share using mount -t cifs

Tags: linux, samba, cifs, unmounting

All,

I have a SUSE SLES 11 box running samba. I am running this command:

```
mount -t cifs //ip/dir1/dir2 /mnt/backups -o username=user,password=pwd,domain=domain
```

Which works and mounts the drive properly. I can access all contents of dir2 via

```
ls /mnt/backups
```

Now I use used umount /mnt/backups, and try to access a directory deeper...

```
mount -t cifs //ip/dir1/dir2/dir3 /mnt/backups -o username=user,password=pwd,domain=domain
```

The command does not return any errors, but when I type *ls /mnt/backups*, I get

```
/bin/ls: /mnt/backups: No such file or directory
```

The permissions on all folders in the directory are fine. When I am able to mount dir2, I can navigate to the dir3 using ls. However, I cannot mount dir3. Is there a restriction on how deep you can go (as far as directories)?

Comment: try moving `-o ...` to after `-t cifs` before `//ip/..`